# Grouping checkboxes css in multiple column layout

Tags: html, css

I have the following html

```
<fieldset class="group"> 
<legend>Select standard pizza toppings</legend> 
<ul class="checkbox"> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb1" value="pepperoni" /><label for="cb1">Pepperoni</label></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb2" value="sausage" /><label for="cb2">Sausage</label></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb3" value="mushrooms" /><label for="cb3">Mushrooms</label></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb4" value="onions" /><label for="cb4">Onions</label></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb5" value="gpeppers" /><label for="cb5">Green Peppers</label></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb6" value="xcheese" /><label for="cb6">Extra Cheese</label></li> 
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb7" value="pineapple" /><label for="cb7">Pineapple</label></li> 
</ul> 
</fieldset>
```

and css:

```
fieldset.group  { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  margin-bottom: 1.25em; 
  padding: .125em; 
} 

fieldset.group legend { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  margin-left: 20px; 
  font-size: 100%; 
  color: black; 
} 


ul.checkbox  { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  margin-left: 20px; 
  list-style: none; 
} 

ul.checkbox li input { 
  margin-right: .25em; 
} 

ul.checkbox li { 
  border: 1px transparent solid; 
} 

ul.checkbox li label { 
  margin-left: ; 
} 
ul.checkbox li:hover, 
ul.checkbox li.focus  { 
  background-color: lightyellow; 
  border: 1px gray solid; 
  width: 12em; 
}
```

So far it looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pynhA/). I wanted such that there's only 3 rows in the grouping. So that `peperoni, sausage, mushrooms` belongs to the first column, and then the next column next to it is `gpeppes, xcheese, etc, etc`. What should I modify in my css to have this effect instead of laying all the checkboxes in a single column? In other words I want it to take advantage of the empty space to the right of it..

Comment: try ul.checkbox li { 
  border: 1px transparent solid; 
    float:left;
     width: 12em; 
}

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can add to your `li` a property to make it `inline` elements, an additional set a width to keep two columns:

```
ul.checkbox li { 
  border: 1px transparent solid; 
  display:inline-block;
  width:12em;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/pynhA/2/**

Comment: you saved me!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45178766/how-to-stack-vertically-or-horizontally-two-multicheckboxfield-wtform-fields

Answer (score 5):

The column count property in CSS is pretty helpful. If you put a line break after each form element you can make a pretty clean presentation. Also, by adding <span style="white-space: nowrap;">, it keeps the label attached to the check box element

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.newspaper {
    -webkit-column-count: 6; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 6; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 6;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Here are a bunch of check boxes and their labels laid out nicely
<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions, does not support the column-count property.</p>

<div class="newspaper">

<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="data" value="some value" id="some id" /><label for="pizza stuff">something for your pizza</label></span><br/>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add to your CSS:

```css
.checkbox {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

It will split your content into 2 columns.

Comment: This one align items vertically to the middle. How can I align them to the top please? :)

Answer (score 2):

There is an awesome CSS3 Property available called `column-count`, it can be used to split list elements (`ul` & `ol`) into multiple columns
here is full detailed tutorial [Split Unordered List Into Multiple Columns using CSS3 Property](https://www.myprogrammingtutorials.com/unordered-list-into-multiple-columns.html)

Answer (score 0):

edit this class:

```
ul.checkbox li {
border: 1px transparent solid;
float: left;        /*  added  */
min-width: 200px;   /*  added  */
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pynhA/3/)